# Merge and center cells in phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

im searching for hours in doc but got nothing to merge and horizontal center..

anyone can help me how to do this?

my last code :

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$excel = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$spreadsheet->getProperties()->setTitle($name_sheet)->setCreator('Creator');

$excel->mergeCells('A1:W1');
$excel->mergeCells('A2:W2');
$excel->mergeCells('A3:W3');

//how to make cells A1 till W1 to be centered cell?
```

Answer (score 0):

**At the begin of your page :**
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;

**Definition of the center alignment :**
$excel->getStyle('A1:W1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).